# Swift - SKAction.fadeIn not working when in a group

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, fadein, skaction

I'm trying to get an SKShapeNode to move and fade from 0 alpha to 1 alpha over a 2 second period and then delete itself. The moving part is fine, but when I try to add the fadeIn it fades in very very quickly (in about 0.2 seconds) and repeats itself, so it ends up looking like the SKShapeNode is flashing. Can anyone help? 
Here is my code:

```
func startMoving(){
        alpha = 0
        let move = SKAction.moveBy(x: moveX, y: moveY, duration: 2.0)
        let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 2.0)
        let group = SKAction.group([move, fadeIn])
        run(group, completion: {
            self.removeFromParent()
        })
    }
```

Also, I'm a bit worried that self.removeFromParent() won't actually delete the instance of the node. I'm running this quite a few times, so want to make sure i'm properly taking care of it. I've tried self = nul, but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: my guess is you are calling startMoving 10x

Answer (score 0):

the code you posted is working fine. Your bug is elsewhere.[image: a playground I did to test]

Comment: and the node count is decreased by 1 at the end of the action, as you wrote